# как подписать signTool?

Tags: сертификат, цифровая-подпись, x509certificate, csp, криптопро

Дело такое: есть сервер, на сервере есть два сертификата (родительский с открытым ключом и дочерний с открытым и закрытым ключами), они установлены, т.е. находятся в хранилище. Мне необходимо подписать .dll дочерним сертификатом через signTool. Так как подписывание подразумевает использование сертификата в формате .pfx, то я этот дочерний сертификат из хранилища экспортирую вместе с приватным ключом и дополнительными свойствами. Далее signTool.exe sign /f [путьДоСертификатаДочернего.pfx] /p [Пароль] [ФайлКоторыйНадоПодписать.dll]
В итоге, после нажатия Enter вылетает криптоПро по поводу контейнеров и установки нового пароля. Не понимаю почему и зачем он вываливается. Если я буду подписывать самописным сертификатом, то криптоПро не вываливается.

Подскажите в чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "вываливается"?

Comment: @insolor , просто запускается криптоПро и на экране отображается соответствующее окно по поводу контейнеров

Comment: Прикрепите скриншот к вопросу